# How to send a highlighted cell value to another cell in another column?

Tags: excel, vba

Good Morning,

I made a macro that highlights the cell values that the user inputs, basically what it highlights is values from the column G, I and J. Values from column G has values that either the column I or J have but they are not in order. What I would like my macro to do is to match these values already highlighted and move them to column H, for example if G3 has the same value that I5, move the value from I5 to H3.

```
Public Sub series()
    'Definición de variables (Definition of variables)
    Dim rango As String, valor As String, resultado As Range
    Dim primerResultado As String, cont As Integer

    'Solicitar información al usuario (Get information from the user)
    rango = "A1:XFD1048576"
    valor = InputBox("Ingresa el VALOR a buscar:")
    If valor = "" Then Exit Sub

    cont = 0    'Inicializar contador de coincidencias (Initialize Find)

    'Primera búsqueda del valor dentro del rango (First search for value in the range)
    Set resultado = Range(rango).Find(What:=valor, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not resultado Is Nothing Then    'Si el resultado de la búsqueda no es vacío
        primerResultado = resultado.Address
        Do                              'Inicia bucle para hacer varias búsquedas
            If MsgBox("Resaltar Valor?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                cont = cont + 1
                resultado.Interior.ColorIndex = 4    'Cambia el color de fondo de la celda

            End If
            Set resultado = Range(rango).FindNext(resultado) 'Vuelve a buscar el valor



            ' Display a simple message box.


        Loop While Not resultado Is Nothing And resultado.Address <> primerResultado
           MsgBox ("Valores Encontrados: " & cont)
    Else
        MsgBox "Se encontraron " & cont & " coincidencias."
    End If End Sub
```

Comment: What isn't working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if G3 has the same value that I5, move the value from I5 to H3.

You requirement is strange.

You have written code that highlight cells.

What you are in effect saying is that as well as highighing the cells you want to move them.

However, do you really want to MOVE the value (so it is no longer in the original cell)?  If not then you could simply add a formula to the cell where you want the value to be copied to.

If you do want the VBA to move the value you will need to add code that moves the value after the colour has been applied.

the value can be MOVED easily by adding code after you line:

```
If Not resultado Is Nothing Then
```

add this code

```
    Dim G as integer, H as integer, I as integer
    ' note 7 represents the 7th column ie G

    colG = 7
    colH = 8
    colI = 9 

    if cells(resultado.row,colG) = cells(resultado.row,colI) then 

        ' OPTION 1        
        ' if value in column G has the same value that in column I 
        ' move the value from column I to column H
        cells(resultado.row,colH) = cells(resultado.row,colI)
        resultado.value = ""

        ' OPTION 2        
        ' if G3 has the same value that I5, move the value from I5 to H3.
        ' Note the use of -2
        cells(resultado.row,colH) = cells(resultado.row,colI-2)

        ' now clear teh source cell
        resultado.value = ""


    end if
```

Comment: colG = 7
colH = 8
colI = 9 

These values are not taking columns, they are taking rows. Is there any other way to reference to a column ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: oops sorry.  I have changed this:  cells(colG,resultado.row)    to be this: cells(resultado.row,colG)

Comment: Hi Harvey, this macro just works if the values  are in the same row in column I, is there a way to search for all the values in all the column I and then match it with the values in column G ? After this moving the value from column I and putting it beside the same value in column H. For example if $650 is in G:3 and $650 is in I:7 move the $650 from I:7 and put it in H:3 beside the $650 in G:3.

Comment: You will need to add a nested loop to you code.  Before you write VBA to do it I must ask whether you considered putting VLOOKUP formula in all the cells of column H, as this is an easy excel way of doing this!

Comment: I have not considered the formula, which formula can I use ?